# Setting variable with ReactJS's useState hook does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to set a variable with `useState` after an API call, but it doesn't work. Debugging by reactotron, he makes the API call, but he doesn't set the variable.

```
export default function Forecast({ navigation }) {
  const [cityData, setCityData] = useState([]);
  const idNavigation = navigation.state.params.cityData.woeid;

  async function loadCityData(cityID) {
    const response = await api.get(`${cityID}`);
    setCityData([response]);
    console.tron.log(cityData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (idNavigation) {
      loadCityData(idNavigation);
    }
    return () => {};
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [idNavigation]);

  return <Text>Forecast Weather</Text>;
}

Forecast.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    state: PropTypes.object,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the `console`? Make sure you are getting data in `response `.

Comment: The code looks fine. Could you verify if `response` coming from the API has some data ?

Comment: Yeah maybe it is the HTTP request that you are making. Please check the console.

Comment: The response its ok. The problem it`s the setState, it does nt set the value.

Comment: The log error : possible Unhandled Promise Rejectior, 
  Type error: undefined is not an object(evaluating response data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state in React is async for the most part and the changes to the state might not be visible if you try to console.log them right away. The recommended way to do this with hooks, is to check for the updated state in `useEffect`:

```
 async function loadCityData(cityID) {
  const response = await api.get(`${cityID}`);
  setCityData([response]);
}

// Track cityData and log the changes to it
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(cityData);
}, [cityData]);

// Rest of the code
// ...
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the user is also doing ?

Comment: What the user is doing is setting the data and then call console.log right away, which returns the old state.

Comment: I try it but didn't work. I dont understand. In the code, the await doent works

Comment: The log error : possible Unhandled Promise Rejectior, 
  Type error: undefined is not an object(evaluating response data)

Comment: That's an issue with the api and probably should be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I think it maybe reactotron or api problem.
Just try

```
const [cityData, setCityData] = useState('foo');

...

return <Text>{JSON.stringify(cityData)}</Text>;
```

If your plobrem came from reactron, then you can see the response from API.

Comment: You need react v16.8 to use hooks.
"React v16.7: No, This Is Not the One With Hooks"
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/12/19/react-v-16-7.html

Answer (score 0):

because useState is asynchronous function.

```
    setCityData([response]); // asynchronous function so not set the new data to state yet.
    console.tron.log(cityData);// so you get the old data.
```

***See this Example***

```js
const Forecast = ({ idNavigation }) => {
    const [cityData, setCityData] = React.useState([]);
  
    function loadCityData(cityID) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCityData([1,2,3,4,5]);
        console.log("this is old data", cityID, cityData); // because useState is asynchronous function
      }, 2000);
    }
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (idNavigation) {
        console.log("load ", idNavigation);
        loadCityData(idNavigation);
      }
    }, [idNavigation]);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if(cityData.length > 0) {
        console.log("this is new data", cityData);
      }
    }, [cityData]); // when cityData changed and component mounted, this function called.
  
    return <div>Forecast Weather</div>;
  }
  
  class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      id: 1,
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({id: 2});
      }, 2000);
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Forecast idNavigation={this.state.id}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render( <App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

***Solution***

if you use Class Component you can use callback of `setState()` function.
but if you use Functional Component you can't use a callback.
so you should use `useEffect()` to solve this problem.